# Уместно ли применение mysql_fetch_assoc везде?

Tags: mysql

Всем привет.

Привык пользоваться командой `mysql_fetch_assoc`, причем всегда, и не вижу различий в скорости (юзабилити сайта) работы и удобстве с командами `mysql_fetch_row`, `mysql_fetch_array`... может ли кто подсказать, на языке дилетанта, так сказать, где полезно юзать вышеперечисленные команды, а где лучше не использовать?

Comment: Везде, где вам удобно использовать fetch_assoc - используйте его, различий в скорости вы не заметили потому-что их практически нет (вернее ими смело можно пренебречь)

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc вообще неуместно использовать. нигде.

Comment: уважаемые гуру, привидите хотя бы 2 аргумента за, или против, а то глядя на 2 верхних комментария не знаю кому верить

Comment: Два аргумета привели)

Comment: стыдно должно быть за такие аргументы, чему молодежь учите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> уважаемые гуру, привидите хотя бы 2
> аргумента за, или против, а то глядя
> на 2 верхних комментария не знаю кому
> верить

`mysql_fetch_array -> $arr[0]` и `$arr['id']` вернут одно и тоже из БД

`mysql_fetch_assoc` -> `$arr[0]` вернет `Undefined offset: 0`

Допустим используя функцию `list()` индексами которой являются числа, при запросе данных функцией `mysql_fetch_assoc` ничего не вернет кроме `Undefined offset`

Примеров и тонкостей использования много! Привел первый что вспомнил!

Answer (score 2):

mysql_* функции небезопасные и устаревшие плюс еще куча других минусов, поэтому реккомендуется использовать библиотеку PDO. [Почему следует использовать PDO](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/)

Comment: @FLK - я ответил на конкретный вопрос ТС'а, а по хорошему - да, действительно лучше использовать PDO.

По поводу небезопасные, дабы не быть голословным - предоставьте пожалуйста пруф.

Да и не везде PDO уместно, например если пишется процедурный код

Comment: во первых в php отсутствует процедурный код как таковой, по поводу безопасности, как минимум, всеми любимая конструкция: mysql_query("select * from `table` where id=$id"); уже небезопасна.

Answer (score 1):

Если путаешься используй `mysql_fetch_array` с параметром `MYSQL_BOTH`, это совокупность `mysql_fetch_assoc` и `mysql_fetch_row`. Я в 90% случаев использую `mysql_fetch_assoc`, просто потому что мне нравиться сочетание буковок в этой фразе ))) Да и как то по моему приятней читается )) Все мы программисты со своими странностями ))))

Вот в дакидку прмиеры использования:

```
function MySQLQ_once($q)
{
  $res = MySQLQ($q);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_NUM))
    return $row[0];
 return false;
}

function MySQLQ_array($q)
{
  $res = MySQLQ($q);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    return $row;
return false;
}
```